# Solve differential equation $-f'(x)= a_1 f(a_2 x+a_3)$ with $f(0)=1$.

Tags: delay-differential-equations

How to solve the following differential equation

\begin{align}
-f'(x)= a_1 f(a_2 x+a_3),
\end{align}
where $f(0)=1$.

I looked around I think this falls under the category of discrete delayed differential equations.

Comment: Your problem is ill posed. Defining just one point of $f$ will not be enough to determine the solution.

Comment: @Artem would value as $x \to -\infty$ be good enough?  Or the value of $f'(0)$?

Answer (score 2):

*Introductory comments:*

If it's okay, I will assume $a_2>0$. (But if you're keen to have $a_2<0$ as well, write a comment and I'll see if I have time to work out that case.) The term "(discrete) delay differential equation" would apply to the case that $a_2=1$ and $a_3<0$.

As stated in one of the comments under your question, to uniquely determine a solution it is not enough to specify the value of $f$ at just a single point. Instead, as is typically the case for delay differential equations, an "initial condition" consists of specifying $f$ on a suitable interval! If this "initial condition" satisfies a certain requirement then it gives rise to a solution and this solution is unique. All this will be described below.

If $a_2 \neq 1$, then one needs to consider your differential equation *separately* over the range $x \in (\frac{a_3}{1-a_2},\infty)$ and the range $x \in (-\infty,\frac{a_3}{1-a_2})$. For each of these two cases one needs to specify an "initial condition" consisting of the values of $f$ over a suitable interval.

---

Let us define $T \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $T(x)=a_2x+a_3$, and if $a_2 \neq 1$ then we write $X_0$ for the fixed point of $T$, namely $X_0=\frac{a_3}{1-a_2}$. We write $T^n$ for the $n$-th iterate of $T$ if $n>0$, or for the $|n|$-th iterate of the inverse of $T$ if $n<0$ (and we let $T^0$ be the identity function). Explicitly, for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$,
$$ T^n(x) \ = \ \left\{ \begin{array}{c l} a_2^nx+\frac{a_3(1-a_2^n)}{1-a_2} & a_2 \neq 1 \\ x + na_3 & a_2=1 \end{array} \right. $$

**(I)** First suppose $a_2 \in (0,1)$. To construct a solution $f(x)$ on the range $x \in (X_0,\infty)$, you need to specify a suitable "initial condition".  To specify a suitable "initial condition", you choose an $x_0 \in (X_0,\infty)$ and specify the function $f$ on $[x_0,T^{-1}(x_0)]$. In order for this initial condition $\left. f \right|_{[x_0,T^{-1}(x_0)]}$ to give rise to a solution on $(X_0,\infty)$, we need that $\left. f \right|_{[x_0,T^{-1}(x_0)]}$ is $C^\infty$ with the additional boundary requirement
$$ f^{(k+1)}(T^{-1}(x_0)) = -a_1f^{(k)}(x_0) $$
for all $k \geq 0$. In this case, we construct the unique solution on $(X_0,\infty)$ as follows: define $f$ on $(X_0,x_0)$ by
$$ f(x) = (-a_1)^{-n}f^{(n)}(T^{-n}(x)) $$
for $x \in [T^n(x_0),T^{n-1}(x_0))$ with $n \geq 1$; and define $f$ on $(T^{-1}(x_0),\infty)$ by constructing $f$ recursively on the intervals $(T^{-n}(x_0),T^{-(n+1)}(x_0)]$ with $n \geq 1$, by
$$ f(x) \ = \ f(T^{-n}(x_0)) - a_1 \int_{T^{-n}(x_0)}^x f(T(y)) \, dy. $$
Thus we have constructed $f$ on $(X_0,\infty)$; it is easy to check that our constructed function $f$ solves the differential equation, and it is not hard to see that it is the only possible solution on $(X_0,\infty)$ given the initial condition. (And in a similar way, it is not hard to see that if the initial condition fails to satisfy the boundary requirement, then it cannot give rise to a solution on $(X_0,\infty)$.)

Likewise one can construct a solution on $(-\infty,X_0)$ given a suitable "initial condition". To define a suitable initial condition, you choose an $x_1 \in (-\infty,X_0)$ and specify $f$ on $[T^{-1}(x_1),x_1]$. For this initial condition $\left. f \right|_{[T^{-1}(x_1),x_1]}$ to give rise to a solution on $(-\infty,X_0)$, we need that $\left. f \right|_{[T^{-1}(x_1),x_1]}$ is $C^\infty$ with the additional boundary requirement
$$ f^{(k+1)}(T^{-1}(x_1)) = -a_1f^{(k)}(x_1) $$
for all $k \geq 0$. In this case, to construct the solution, define $f$ on $(x_1,X_0)$ by
$$ f(x) = (-a_1)^{-n}f^{(n)}(T^{-n}(x)) $$
for $x \in (T^{n-1}(x_1),T^n(x_1)]$ with $n \geq 1$, and define $f$ on $(-\infty,T^{-1}(x_1))$ by constructing $f$ recursively on the intervals $[T^{-(n+1)}(x_1),T^{-n}(x_1))$ with $n \geq 1$, by
$$ f(x) \ = \ f(T^{-n}(x_1)) + a_1 \int_x^{T^{-n}(x_1)} f(T(y)) \, dy. $$
Thus we have constructed a solution on $(-\infty,X_0)$.

**(II)** Suppose $a_2>1$. To define a suitable "initial condition" for a solution on $(X_0,\infty)$, you choose an $x_0 \in (X_0,\infty)$ and specify $f$ on $[x_0,T(x_0)]$ with $\left. f \right|_{[x_0,T(x_0)]}$ being $C^\infty$ and satisfying the boundary requirement
$$ f^{(k+1)}(x_0) = -a_1f^{(k)}(T(x_0)) $$
for all $k \geq 0$. With this, define $f$ on $(T(x_0),\infty)$ by
$$ f(x) = (-a_1)^{-n}f^{(n)}(T^{-n}(x)) $$
for $x \in (T^n(x_0),T^{n+1}(x_0)]$ with $n \geq 1$, and define $f$ on $(X_0,x_0)$ by constructing $f$ recursively on the intervals $[T^{-n}(x_0),T^{-(n-1)}(x_0))$ with $n \geq 1$, by
$$ f(x) \ = \ f(T^{-(n-1)}(x_0)) + a_1 \int_x^{T^{-(n-1)}(x_0)} f(T(y)) \, dy. $$
To define a suitable "initial condition" for a solution on $(-\infty,X_0)$, you choose an $x_1 \in (\infty,X_0)$ and specify $f$ on $[T(x_1),x_1]$ with $\left. f \right|_{[T(x_1),x_1]}$ being $C^\infty$ and satisyfing the boundary requirement
$$ f^{(k+1)}(x_1) = -a_1f^{(k)}(T(x_1)) $$
for all $k \geq 0$. With this, define $f$ on $(-\infty,T(x_1))$ by
$$ f(x) = (-a_1)^{-n}f^{(n)}(T^{-n}(x)) $$
for $x \in [T^{n+1}(x_1),T^n(x_1))$ with $n \geq 1$, and define $f$ on $(x_1,X_0)$ by constructing $f$ recursively on the intervals $(T^{-(n-1)}(x_1),T^{-n}(x_1)]$ with $n \geq 1$ by
$$ f(x) \ = \ f(T^{-(n-1)}(x_1)) - a_1 \int_{T^{-(n-1)}(x_1)}^x f(T(y)) \, dy. $$
Finally, given a solution $f$ on $(-\infty,X_0) \cup (X_0,\infty)$, it is not hard to show [I think!] that the left-sided and right-sided limits of $f$ at $X_0$ exist; if they are equal to each other, then setting $f(X_0)$ to be equal to this limit gives a solution on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ (and this solution is $C^\infty$ on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$).

**(III)** Suppose $a_2=1$ and $a_3>0$. Given a suitable initial condition, one can construct a solution on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. To define a suitable initial condition, you choose an $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and specify $f$ on the interval $[x_0,T(x_0)]=[x_0,x_0+a_3]$. The boundary requirement for this initial condition to have a solution, and the construction of the solution on $\mathbb{R}$, are exactly the same as given in Case (II) for constructing solutions on $(X_0,\infty)$ when $a_2>1$. To be precise, the initial condition $\left. f \right|_{[x_0,x_0+a_3]}$ has to be $C^\infty$ with the boundary requirement
$$ f^{(k+1)}(x_0) = -a_1f^{(k)}(x_0+a_3) $$
for all $k \geq 0$. With this, define $f$ on $(x_0+a_3,\infty)$ by
$$ f(x) = (-a_1)^{-n}f^{(n)}(x-na_3) $$
for $x \in (x_0+na_3,x_0+(n+1)a_3]$ with $n \geq 1$, and define $f$ on $(-\infty,x_0)$ by constructing $f$ recursively on the intervals $[x_0-na_3,x_0-(n-1)a_3)$ with $n \geq 1$, by
$$ f(x) \ = \ f(x_0-(n-1)a_3) + a_1 \int_x^{x_0-(n-1)a_3} f(y+a_3) \, dy. $$

**(IV)** Suppose $a_2=1$ and $a_3<0$. Given a suitable initial condition, one can construct a solution on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$. To define a suitable initial condition, you choose an $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and specify $f$ on the interval $[x_0,T^{-1}(x_0)]=[x_0,x_0+|a_3|]$. The boundary requirement for this initial condition to have a solution, and the construction of the solution on $\mathbb{R}$, are exactly the same as given in Case (I) for constructing solutions on $(X_0,\infty)$ when $a_2 \in (0,1)$. To be precise, the initial condition $\left. f \right|_{[x_0,x_0+|a_3|]}$ has to be $C^\infty$ with the boundary requirement
$$ f^{(k+1)}(x_0+|a_3|) = -a_1f^{(k)}(x_0) $$
for all $k \geq 0$. With this, define $f$ on $(-\infty,x_0)$ by
$$ f(x) = (-a_1)^{-n}f^{(n)}(x+n|a_3|) $$
for $x \in [x_0-n|a_3|,x_0-(n-1)|a_3|)$ with $n \geq 1$, and define $f$ on $(x_0+|a_3|,\infty)$ by constructing $f$ recursively on the intervals $(x_0+n|a_3|,x_0+(n+1)|a_3|]$ with $n \geq 1$, by
$$ f(x) \ = \ f(x_0+n|a_3|) - a_1 \int_{x_0+n|a_3|}^x f(y-|a_3|) \, dy. $$

**Remark.** Case (IV) is a simple case of a "delay differential equation". For this case (as with delay differential equations in general) one is likely to be concerned only with *"forward-time solutions"*. Assuming $a_2=0$ and $a_3<0$, a "forward-time solution" of your differential equation is a function $f \colon [x_0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ (for some $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$) such that your differential equation is satisfied on $[x_0+|a_3|,\infty)$ (with only the right-sided derivative considered at the left endpoint $x_0+|a_3|$). To define a forward-time solution, the "initial condition" that one needs to specify is the function $f$ on the interval $[x_0,x_0+|a_3|]$; this initial condition $\left. f \right|_{[x_0,x_0+|a_3|]}$ may be any continuous function!$^\ast$ From here, one defines $f$ on $(x_0+|a_3|,\infty)$ by the recursive procedure described above for Case (IV). An example in the case that $x_0=a_3$ (so $x_0+|a_3|=0$) and $\left. f \right|_{[a_3,0]}$ is constant at $1$ is given in the Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation.

---

$^\ast$In fact, for "weak" forward-time solutions (meaning that differentiability on $[x_0+|a_3|,\infty)$ can be weakend to weak differentiability on $[x_0+|a_3|,\infty)$), $\left. f \right|_{[x_0,x_0+|a_3|]}$ can be any $L^1$ function, although one would additionally need to specify the value of $\lim_{x \searrow x_0+|a_3|} f(x)$.

Comment: I realise my initial reply may not have been so clear; so I have made changes with a slightly more "pedagogical" style.

Comment: For case (I) ($0<a_2<1$), what I wrote about solutions on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ is wrong, so I have removed it. I can think about that further. The answer by Yuri Negometyanov constructs one possible solution for this case via Taylor series [the unique analytic solution when $f$ is specified at a single point - unless the specified value happens to be at a point $x$ where the Taylor series around $X_0$ converges to $0$], although I expect that there will also be other non-analytic solutions.

Comment: On second thoughts, I have no idea whether analytic solutions do exist.

Comment: Nothing specific solutions, common ideas only.

Comment: To "solve" a differential equation does not mean to give some examples of solutions, but rather to obtain (for given parameter-values) the complete set of solutions, ideally in such a manner that if you give me sufficient "initial data" of any solution, I can tell you the entire solution. For "initial data" taking the form of specifying $f$ on an interval, my answer achieves this for $a_2=1$ when the DE is interpreted on $\mathbb{R}$, and for $a_2\in (0,\infty)\setminus\{1\}$ when the DE is interpreted on $(-\infty,X_0)$ or $(X_0,\infty)$.

Comment: The two main improvements that could be made to my answer are: (i) to express the solutions as some kind of "closed form expression" rather than a recursive definition (which is probably possible, but I don't know how to do so); and (ii) to determine the set of solutions on the whole of $\mathbb{R}$ when $a_2 \in (0,\infty) \setminus \{1\}$. [I have a vague but correct description of this set when $a_2>1$, but not when $a_2 \in (0,1)$.] Of course, also obtaining the set of solutions for $a_2<0$ would be nice!

Comment: "To solve" DE under the conditions means to get functions which satisfy to them. If the task contains parameters then their influence should be described too.

Comment: "To solve" DE under the conditions means to get *all* the functions which satisfy them, not just some. For example, in the case that $a_2=1$, given the value for $f(0)$, your exponential function solution is one (very nice!) example of a solution but there are infinitely many more solutions (unless $a_3=0$).

Answer (score 1):

Case $1$: $a_2>0$

Let $f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}K(t)~dt$ ,

Then $\int_0^\infty te^{-xt}K(t)~dt=a_1\int_0^\infty e^{-(a_2x+a_3)t}K(t)~dt$

$\int_0^\infty te^{-xt}K(t)~dt-a_1\int_0^\infty e^{-a_2xt}e^{-a_3t}K(t)~dt=0$

$a_2^2\int_0^\infty te^{-a_2xt}K(a_2t)~dt-a_1\int_0^\infty e^{-a_2xt}e^{-a_3t}K(t)~dt=0$

$\int_0^\infty e^{-a_2xt}(a_2^2tK(a_2t)-a_1e^{-a_3t}K(t))~dt=0$

$\therefore a_2^2tK(a_2t)-a_1e^{-a_3t}K(t)=0$

Let $\begin{cases}t_1=\log_{a_2}t\\K_1(t_1)=K(t)\end{cases}$ ,

Then $a_2^{t_1+2}K_1(t_1+1)=a_1e^{-a_3a_2^{t_1}}K_1(t_1)$

Answer (score 0):

**Edition of 06.03.19**

---

First, if $\underline{a_1=0}$ or $\underline{a_2=0},$ then $f(x)=0.$

If $\underline{a_2=1},$ then finding of the solution in the form of
$$f(x)= \mathrm{const}\cdot e^{-kx}\tag1$$
gives
$$ke^{-kx} = a_1e^{-kx-ka_3},$$
$$ke^{ka_3}=a_1,$$
$$k=
\begin{cases}
a_1,\quad\text{if}\quad a_3=0,\\[4pt]
\dfrac{\log(a_1a_3)}{a_3 W(\log(a_1a_3))},\quad\text{otherwize},
\end{cases}\tag2
$$
where $W(t)$ is the [Lambert W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html).

---

Assume $\underline{a_1\not=0},\quad \underline{a_2\not = 0},\quad \underline{a_2\not= 1}.$

Taking in account that
$$f'\left(\frac{a_3}{1-a_2} - x\right) = a_1f\left(\frac{a_2a_3}{1-a_2}-a_2x+a_3\right) = a_1f\left(a_2\left(\frac{a_3}{a_2(1-a_2)}-x\right)\right),$$
denote
$$r=\frac{a_3}{a_2(1-a_2)},\quad y=r-x,\quad g(y) = f\left(\dfrac y{a_1}\right).\tag3$$
Then 
$$g'(y) = \dfrac1{a_1}f'\left(\dfrac y{a_1}\right) = f\left(\dfrac{a_2}{a_1}\,y\right),$$
$$g'(y) = g(a_2y),\quad g(r) = 1.\tag4$$

Boundary condition defines factor of $g(y).$ Behavior of $g(y)$ is linked with the parameter $a_2.$

Denote $v=g(0),$ and let us calculate derivatives of $g(y):$
\begin{align}
&g(0) = v,\\[4pt]
&g'(y) = g(a_2y),\quad g'(0) = v,\\[4pt]
&g''(y) = a_2 g'(a_2 y) = a_2g(a_2^2y),\quad g''(0) = a_2v,\\[4pt]
&g'''(y) = a_2^3 g'(a_2^2y) = a_2^3 g(a_2^3y),\quad g'''(0) = a_2^3v,\dots,\\[4pt]
&g^{(n)}(y) =a_2^{\frac12n(n-1)}g\left(a_2^{\frac12n(n-1)}\right),\quad 
g^{(n)}(0) =a_2^{\frac12n(n-1)}v,\dots
\end{align}
Maclaurin series are
$$g(y) = v \left(1+y+\frac12a_2y^2+\frac16a_2^3y^3+\dots+\dfrac1{n!}a_2^{\frac12n(n-1)}y^n+\dots\right).\tag5$$

If $\underline{|a_2|>1}$ then $n! \le n^n = e^{n\log n},$ and the series $(5)$ diverge.

If $\underline{a_2 = 1}$ then the series $(5)$ converge to $ve^x,$ and then 
$$g(y) = e^{x-r}.\tag6$$
Formula $(6)$ cannot be used in the solution, but it gives a limit case for $g(y).$

If $\underline{a_2 = -1}$ then the series $(5)$ converge to $v(\sin x + \cos x),$ and then 
$$g(y)=\dfrac{\cos\left(\dfrac\pi4-y\right)}{\cos\left(\dfrac\pi4-r\right)}.\tag7$$

If $\underline{|a_2|<1}$ then the series $(5)$ converge, wherein
$$g(y) = \dfrac {\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac1{n!}a_2^{\frac12n(n-1)}y^n}
{\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac1{n!}a_2^{\frac12n(n-1)}r^n}.\tag8$$

[image: Function g(y)]

[The Wolfram Alpha plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20sum_(n%3D0,20)%20(t%5En%20(%7B-9,-6,-3,3,6,9%7D%2F10.)%5E(n(n-1)%2F2)%20%2FGamma(n%2B1)),%20where%20t%3D-5...5) of the numerators of $(8)$ shown above, illustrates the behavior of the function $g(y)$ for $a_2=\pm 0.9, \pm 0.6, \pm 0.3,\quad (y=-5,5).$

The solution of the issue equation in the case $|a_2| < 1$ is
$$f\left(x,\vec a\right) = g(a_1(r-x)).\tag9$$

Comment: For a2 in (-1,1), how do you know that the function you constructed solves the differential equation? You've only constructed it to be the analytic function fulfilling the requirement at r itself.

Comment: @JulianNewman Thanks for the comment. See detalized solution.

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental error in your new answer: in the line $f'\left(\frac{a_3}{1-a_2}-x\right)=\ldots$, the rightmost term in the equality is missing "$+a_3$"; i.e. it reads "$\ldots=a_1f\left(a_2\left(\frac{a_3}{1-a_2}-x\right)\right)$" but it should read $\hspace{20mm}$"$\ldots=a_1f\left(a_2\left(\frac{a_3}{1-a_2}-x\right)+a_3\right)$". This error goes all the way through. [Minor points: There should also be a $-$ sign somewhere if we follow the notation of the question; and in the middle term of that line, the $-a_3$ should be $+a_3$.]

Comment: @JulianNewman It was a typo without further influence ( "$-a_3$" instead "$+a_3$".Thanks for attention, fixed.

Comment: You have corrected my "Minor point" which, as you say, has no further influence. But you have not corrected my main concern, namely that the +a3 is still missing from the rightmost term of that line. This error does have further influence. You have persuaded me that for |a2| less than 1, your Taylor series approach constructs a solution of the differential equation if a3=0, but I'm not yet convinced for non-zero a3.

Comment: @JulianNewman Thanks. Fixed.)

Comment: Okay, I think this looks right now.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously $f(x)$ is in $C^{\infty}(\textbf{R})$. Also it hold by induction
$$
f^{(\nu)}(x)=(-a_1)^{\nu}a_2^{\nu(\nu-1)/2}f\left(g_n(x)\right)\textrm{, }\forall x\in\textbf{R}
$$
I.e if $g(x)=a_2x+a_3$, then 
$$
g_n(x)=(a_3+a_2(a_3+a_2(a_3+\ldots+a_2(a_3+a_2x\underbrace{)\ldots)))}_{n-parenthesis}.
$$
Hence
$$
f^{(\nu)}(x)=(-1)^{\nu}a_1^{\nu}a_2^{\nu(\nu-1)/2}f\left(a_3(1+a_2^1+a_2^2+\ldots+a_2^{\nu-1})+a_2^{\nu} x\right)\textrm{, }\forall \nu=1,2,\ldots.
$$
Hence when $\nu=1,2,\ldots$, we get
$$
f^{(\nu)}(-\frac{a_3}{a_2-1})=(-a_1)^{\nu}a_2^{\nu(\nu-1)/2}f\left(-\frac{a_3}{a_2-1}\right).
$$
If we set $c=\frac{a_3}{1-a_2}$,then
$$
f(x)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{f^{(n)}(c)}{n!}(x-c)^{n}=f(c)\left(1+\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{a_2^{n(n-1)/2}(-a_1)^{n}}{n!}(x-c)^n\right),
$$
for all $x\in\textbf{R}$, when $|a_2|<1$.

Comment: This is the same as Yuri Negometyanov's answer before he edited it. As in my initial comment to Yuri Negometyanov: you've constructed an analytic function on $\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies the requirement of the differential equation at the single point $c$, but how do you know that it solves the differential equation everywhere else?

Comment: No. The point $c$ is known constant $a_3/(1-a_2)$. Also the convergent of the function $f(x)$ as given by the Taylor series has ratio all $\textbf{R}$, when $|a_2|<1$, and diverges (has no solution) when $|a_2|>1$. The case $|a_2|=1$ gives also solution. It hapens to be, that in particular point $c$ the Taylor coefficients simplified much more and thats all. In any other point we have the same function.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is analytic in $\textbf{R}$, then Taylor's theorem read as $f(x)=\sum_{n\geq0}f^{(n)}(x_0)/n! (x-x_0)^n$, for every $x_0$ in $\textbf{R}$ and $x$ in $\textbf{R}$. For example with $f(x)=e^x$ it does not matter what is $x_0$, we have $e^x=\sum_{n\geq 0}e^{x_0}/n!(x-x_0)^n$.

Comment: This is my solution and my previous approach.

Comment: I understand that the function you constructed is well-defined on the whole real line and can be constructed by its own Taylor series around any point on the real line. That's not my issue. My issue is that the function you constructed needs to satisfy the differential equation everywhere on the real line, but your construction only verifies the differential equation at the single point you chose for the base of the Taylor series. (And you had to choose that particular point to be able to determine the Taylor series, so it wasn't really just a matter of simplification.)

Comment: Your equation is $f'(x)=-a_1f(a_2x+a_3)$: $(eq)$. So you assume that exist the derivative of $f$. Hence from $(eq)$, since exist the derivative, $f(x)$ must be and continuous also. Hence again from $(eq)$, $f'(x)$ is continuous. Differentiating $(eq)$ (since $f'(x)$ and $f(x)$ are differentiatable functions) we get that $f''(x)$ is continuous and diffentiatable,$\ldots$, $f$ is entire. Hence regarding your (eq), there are no solutions to your problem when $|a_2|>1$ at all.

Comment: Since seeing Yuri Negometyanov's edit, I now do believe that the function you constructed for $|a_2|<1$ is a solution of the differential equation: the key to verifying this is simply to notice that (using your notation) $g(x)-c=a_2(x-c)$; then one can verify directly that your function $f(x)$ satisfies $-f'(x)=a_1f(g(x))$ as required.

Comment: Regarding the case $|a_2|>1$: I guess from your comment that you are interpreting the differential equation as being on the whole of $\mathbb{C}$? I was just interpreting the differential equation as being (at most!) just on $\mathbb{R}$, in which case solutions *do* exist (but as you have proved, they are not analytic). [Similarly, for $a_2 \in (0,1)$ I expect that there probably are additional non-analytic solutions beyond the analytic solution you constructed, if we interpret the differential equation just on $\mathbb{R}$ rather than on $\mathbb{C}$.]

Comment: The last formula looks as the new equation which should be solved.

Comment: Ok. I got it. I search in the Web for time delay equations. There have infinite number of solutions and mainly are solved with numerical methods. I was confused by the above thoughts, in which to me seems too natural. I have written in the past an article in arXiv about these kind of equations without knowing about the related theory maybe will be helpful: https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2570